# Heaps law in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to plot Heaps law for a given text (it shows the growth of vocabulary size in function of the length of the text). That is, for each token i need the length of the text and the vocabulary size up to the given token

I have already tokenised my text, but I am stuck because I don't know how to iterate over all words in the text.

```
tokens=nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text)
it=len(tokens)
i=1
for word in tokens:
    print len(tokens), len(set(tokens))
    i=i+1
    if i>it:
        break
```

I basically need at each iteration for the text to grow by 1 token.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tokens` is an array that is populated once by NLTK. It doesn't grow as you iterate over it, so `len(tokens)` will be the same on every iteration. Since you are already accumulate the count in `i`. Use that instead of `len(tokens)`.

For the unique count, you have the same problem. `set(tokens)` is always the full set, not the ones you've traversed so far. You need to accumulate the set of known words as you go:

```
i = 0
words = set()
for word in tokens:
    words.add(word)
    i += 1
    print i, len(words)
```

Edit: Silly I forgot about enumerate. See Dvir Volk's answer for how to avoid counting `i` explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumerate` to avoid incrementing a counter:

```
uniq = set()

for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
    uniq.add(token)
    print "%d => %d" % (i, len(uniq))
```

Answer (score 1):

`for word in tokens:` does all you need. You don't need to count and break - the loop will terminate after all tokens were exhausted.
Inside the loop, you should examine the `word` variable and do whatever counting you want.

If you want to count distinct words, you can use `set(tokens)`.
A set can contain the same word just once, so `len(set(tokens))` is the number of distinct words. You can also itereate on the set (`for word in set(tokens):`.